# QML xmlhttprequest and curl are getting different results

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to get a soap response in QML using xmlhttprequest. ( i know qml xhr is different ). when i run it with curl i get exactly what i want.

```
curl -u user:pass https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx -d "@ews.xml" -H "Content-Type:text/xml" | xmllint --format -
```

It is basic auth and the ews.xml is the same as the var below in QML

```
function getEWS() {
    var user = ""
    var password = ""
    var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><soap:Body><m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow"><m:ItemShape><t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape><t:AdditionalProperties><t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:DisplayName" /><t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" /><t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Importance" /><t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:HasAttachments" /><t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DateTimeSent" /><t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Location" /><t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Organizer" /><t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start" /><t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:End" /></t:AdditionalProperties></m:ItemShape><m:CalendarView MaxEntriesReturned="5" StartDate="2020-02-01T00:00:00.000-05:00" EndDate="2020-03-01T00:00:00.000-05:00" /><m:ParentFolderIds><t:FolderId Id="AQAW" ChangeKey="AgAA" /></m:ParentFolderIds></m:FindItem></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
    var url = "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true, user, password);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            //console.log(xmlhttp.responseText.toString())
        }
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === xmlhttp.DONE) {
          console.log(xmlhttp.response, xmlhttp.responseXML, xmlhttp.status);
        }
    }
    //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Qt.btoa(user + ":" + password));
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml");
    xmlhttp.send(xml);
}
```

The response i get from xhr is

```html
<HTML lang="en"><HEAD><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="
https://sn6pr06mb6447.namprd06.prod.outlook.com:444/EWS/Exchange.asmx?disco"/><STYLE
 type="text/css">#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em;
MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR:
#000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP:
0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY:
Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px;
BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px;
FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid;
PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY:
Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px;
PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-
BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%;
COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-
COLOR: #003366}.intro{display: block; font-size:
1em;}</STYLE><TITLE>Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><DIV id="content"
role="main"><h1 class="heading1">Service</h1><BR/><P class="intro">You have created a service.<P class='intro'>To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:</P> <BR/><PRE>svcutil.exe <A HREF="
https://sn6pr06mb6447.namprd06.prod.outlook.com:444/EWS/Services.wsdl">https://sn6pr06mb6447.namprd06.prod.outlook.com:444/EWS/Services.wsdl</A></PRE></P><P
 class="intro">This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service. For
example:<BR/></P><h2 class='intro'>C#</h2><br /><PRE><font color="blue">class </font><font color="black">Test </font>{
<font color="blue">    static void </font>Main()
    {
        <font color="black">HelloClient</font> client = <font color="blue">new </font><font color="black">HelloClient</font>();

<font color="darkgreen">        // Use the 'client' variable to call
operations on the service.

</font><font color="darkgreen">        // Always close the client.
</font>        client.Close();
    }
}
</PRE><BR/><h2 class='intro'>Visual Basic</h2><br /><PRE><font color="blue">Class </font><font color="black">Test
</font><font color="blue">    Shared Sub </font>Main()
<font color="blue">        Dim </font>client As <font
color="black">HelloClient</font> = <font color="blue">New </font><font
color="black">HelloClient</font>()
<font color="darkgreen">        ' Use the 'client' variable to call
operations on the service.

</font><font color="darkgreen">        ' Always close the client.
</font>        client.Close()
<font color="blue">    End Sub
</font><font color="blue">End Class</font></PRE></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

i also tried changing the user-agent and other headers but they do not make a difference. Removing the auth gives me a 401 so i know the basic auth is working. How can i get the same results

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the network communications with something like wireshark to see how they differ?

Comment: HTTP is deterministic so the same request should always return the same response. So, on this basis, if you get different response it is worth assuming that you send different request. I would check that with some application like Postman, it can work in server mode.

Comment: btw, check my [qm-soap](https://github.com/folibis/qml-soap) plugin, maybe it could help you.

Comment: it turns out it needs to be xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true, user, password);